# Transform multiple row to column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, row, transform

i have this data. I would like to transform the rows to column. I have try the query below:

```
userid account
001     123
001     456
002     789
002     123
002     467
```

i would like the result to be like this:

```
userid  account 1  account 2   account 3
001      123         456         null
002      789         123         467
```

i have tried this query,but it doesn't work

```
df = df.set_index(['userid'])['account'].unstack()
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
    df.groupby('userid')
    .account.apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'account {int(x)+1}')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the header column with `groupby.cumcount` and then `pivot`:

```
df['cols'] = 'account ' + df.groupby('userid').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df
#   userid  account       cols
#0       1      123  account 1
#1       1      456  account 2
#2       2      789  account 1
#3       2      123  account 2
#4       2      467  account 3

df.pivot(index='userid', columns='cols', values='account').reset_index()

#cols  userid  account 1  account 2  account 3
#0          1      123.0      456.0        NaN
#1          2      789.0      123.0      467.0
```